# How do I implement the 'Mobile Input Picker' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I wanted to create a form where the user will have to input his date of birth. However I do not want to use Date Time picker because it is not appropriate for dates in the distant past according to material.io.

How do I thus implement this one?
[Mobile Date Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLDx1.png)

I have searched everywhere for the codes but couldn't find any.
I only found codes for date time picker below

```
  DateTimePicker(
  initialValue: '',
  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
  dateLabelText: 'Date',
  onChanged: (val) => print(val),
  validator: (val) {
    print(val);
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (val) => print(val),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `initialEntryMode` to `DatePickerEntryMode.input`.

```dart
TextButton(
  child: Text('My Button'),
  onPressed: () async {
    final date = await showDatePicker(
        initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
        context: context,
        initialDate: value ?? _fallBackDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    yourUpdateDateFunction(date);
  });
```